# Method to return a desire Component

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I want to create a method that return a JTextField/JPasswordField based on my parameter Component, and i want after initialization of component to override the paintmethod, is there any solution for this? 
This is my code:

```
public static Component Create(int size,int x, int y, int width, int height, Component type) {
        Component element;
        if (type instanceof JTextField) {
            element = new JTextField(size);
        }else if (type instanceof JPasswordField) {
            element = new JPasswordField(size);
        }
        element{
              /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    if (!isOpaque() && getBorder() instanceof RoundedCornerBorder) {
                      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                      g2.setPaint(getBackground());
                      g2.fill(((RoundedCornerBorder) getBorder()).getBorderShape(
                          0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1));
                      g2.dispose();
                    }
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                  }
                  @Override public void updateUI() {
                    super.updateUI();
                    setOpaque(false);
                    setBorder(new RoundedCornerBorder());
                  }
                };
                element.setBounds(x, y,width, height);
                element.setBackground(culoare);
                
        return element;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Component Create(int size , Component type){
    Component elment;
    //example of instantiation
    elment = new CustomPaintJPassword(size); // new CustomPaintJPassword
        return elment;
}
class CustomPaintJTextField extends JTextField{
 public CustomPaintJTextField(int columns){
     super(columns);
 }
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    /*
     * write paint here
     */
    super.paint(g);
}
}
class CustomPaintJPassword extends JPasswordField{

public CustomPaintJPassword(int columns){
    super(columns);
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    /*
     * write Paint method here
     */
    super.paint(g);
}
}
```

This allows you to write your own paint method while still retaining the Parent class implementation. this is more a less an idea for you to use to achieve what you want. I highly recommend that you do some research on java polymorphism and class extension.[Java polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)